# I can't access static apex field in my visualforce custom page

Tags: apex, visualforce, static

I am newby. 
I've got my custom page:

```
<apex:page controller="opportunityList2Con">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!employees}" var="o" >
            <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.Email__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.Annual_salary__c}"/>    
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!view}" value="View" id="theViewButton" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit" id="theEditButton"/>
    <apex:outputLabel >Total amount of bill </apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:outputText value="{!total}"/>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And my apex class:

```
public class opportunityList2Con {


    public Long total { get; set; }


    public static Long total=444;

    public Long getTotal(){
    return total;
    }
```

That's piece of my class where total variable is defined. 
Unfortunately when i want to display this field, I have no warnings but nothing is printed.
Any idea how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove (or rename) the public property

```
  public Long total { get; set; }
```

For Example:

```
  public class opportunityList2Con {

    public static Long total=444;

    public Long getTotal(){
    return opportunityList2Con.total;
    }
```